# Appending dictionary results to csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I am looking to append a dictionary I have to a CSV file were I already have a header line
and if a value doesn't exist I want to write `'-999'`:

```
SDict ={T1:'A',T2:'B',T4:'D')
```

where CSV file has header of

```
T1,T2,T3,T4,T5
7,8,9,10,11
```

and the expected results are

```
T1,T2,T3,T4,T5
7,8,9,10,11
A,B,-999,D,-999
```

I am trying to do so with the code:

```
import sys
import os
import csv

def GetFileHeader(Fpath):
    i=10
    ResFile=open (Fpath, 'r+')
    HeaderDict={}
    r=csv.reader(ResFile)
    HeaderList = r.next()
    for Header in HeaderList:
        HeaderDict[Header]=i+1
    print HeaderDict
    ResFile.close()
    return HeaderDict


Fpath= r'Z:\temp\assaf\S2TTP\S2T_TP\modules\results\Y124\res.csv'

Header= GetFileHeader(Fpath)

with open(Fpath,'rb') as fin:
    dr = csv.DictReader(fin, dialect='excel')
    print dr
    print dr.fieldnames
# dr.fieldnames contains values from first row of `f`.
with open(Fpath,'ab+') as fou:
    dw = csv.DictWriter(fou, dialect='excel', fieldnames=dr.fieldnames)
    fieldnames=dr.fieldnames
    for K in fieldnames:
        dw.writerow(Header[k])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can simply do:

```
import csv

SDict = {'T1': 'A', 'T2': 'B', 'T4': 'D'}

with open('file.csv', 'r+b') as f:
    header = next(csv.reader(f))
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, header, -999)
    dict_writer.writerow(SDict)
```

This is assuming you're on Python 2.X. Also, be wary of files which don't end in a newline, or you could end up with a row like `7,8,9,10,11A,B,-999,D,-999`.

Comment: thanks,
another question related
if the csv header already  persist is it possible to append the header when updating the results with a new column
let say that at the 4th line i want to add T6 to the header

Comment: @user2740068: Yes, rows are independent of each other so you can do things like this if you want to, e.g do `header.append('T6')` to add T6 to the header and again `dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, header, -999)` to use the new header.

Comment: my header is the dictenery is there a way  to  compare the 2 headers and append the differences ?
take in mind that this is a result file were headers are test and every other line are results
i don't want my header (test name) to change places so other results would show incorect

Comment: @user2740068, Could you explain a little more what you want? Do you want 1 header in the whole file or many headers? Also how many different dictionaries with results do you have?

Comment: i am running a test program on units test program gathers results in a dictionary
1st unit creates the csv result file and the headeres based on tests it run
now i run a 2nd unit and want to add the results row under the first one
but for the 2nd unit i have some aditionl tests that need appending

result file to have 1 header for all units
dict writer promises me that each Test result would be one under the other & for additional test only unit 2 would have results

it can be done by reading the header and then compare loop the keys of the dictionarys
 thought there would be an easy way

Comment: @user2740068, Yes it can be done by comparing keys in a loop. Or in a different way you could use a set, like: `header.extend(set(other_header).difference(header))` where `other_header` is the header from the 2nd unit.. But if you would like more help with this I think it's better to ask a new question `:)`